# Active Passive system setup

Tags: apache-zookeeper, hazelcast, active-passive

I want to implement active passive setup for multiple microservices in a distributed system. We use hazelcast as the messaging layer between our services. Would like to understand the best way to do this. Can we achieve it using zookeeper or does hazelcast natively support this ?

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast is [distributed by nature](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/data-structures/distributed-data-structures.html). You only need to configure your data structures to be replicated.

Here's how you would configure a [single backup for a map](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/data-structures/map.html#backing-up-maps):

```
hazelcast:
  map:
    default:
      backup-count: 1
```